# Como colocar a borda do paragrafo com tamanho mínimo e que deixe o texto sempre dentro da borda

Tags: css

Gostaria de deixar o texto das alternativas sempre dentro da borda, sem quebrar a linha, porém quando abro em algum monitor menor ou diminuo a tela, a borda da caixa de texto invade o texto.

Neste exemplo as bordas do paragrafo não ficam ao redor das letras do paragrafo.

```css
<style type="text/css">
  .geral {
    border: 5px solid lime;
  }
  .pergunta {
    margin: 10px auto;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .alternativa {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 20%;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="geral">
  <p class="pergunta">Qual a alternativa correta?</p>
  <p class="alternativa" id="alt1" onclick="alert('escolheu 1');">Alternativa UM</p>
  <p class="alternativa" id="alt2" onclick="alert('escolheu 2');">Alternativa número DOIS</p>
  <p class="alternativa" id="alt3" onclick="alert('escolheu 3');">Alternativa TRÊS com um texto mais longo</p>
  <p class="alternativa" id="alt4" onclick="alert('escolheu 4');">Alternativa QUATRO com um texto ainda mais longo que o anterior</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso acontece porque a classe `alternativa` tem um limite percentual definido (`width: 20%`). Remover este limite resolve o problema do texto sobressair da borda mas cada alternativa passa a ocupar toda a largura definida. Definir `display: inline-block` também não serve de muito porque fará com que as alternativas fiquem lado a lado.

A minha sugestão é definir `display: flex` no elemento pai e assim poderemos ter as alternativas empilhadas com `flex-direction: column`.

```css
.geral {
  border: 5px solid lime;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.pergunta {
  margin: 10px auto;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
.alternativa {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="geral">
  <p class="pergunta">Qual a alternativa correta?</p>
  <p class="alternativa" id="alt1" onclick="alert('escolheu 1');">Alternativa UM</p>
  <p class="alternativa" id="alt2" onclick="alert('escolheu 2');">Alternativa número DOIS</p>
  <p class="alternativa" id="alt3" onclick="alert('escolheu 3');">Alternativa TRÊS com um texto mais longo</p>
  <p class="alternativa" id="alt4" onclick="alert('escolheu 4');">Alternativa QUATRO com um texto ainda mais longo que o anterior</p>
</div>
```